# Autowiring of SessionFactory not happening

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, wicket

I have a project with:

- Spring : 4.1.7
- Hibernate : 4.3.10
- Wicket: 6.20.0

I am trying to get Hibernate and spring and wicket playing nicely

I have the following code:

init in ? extends WebApplication

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();
    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
}
```

PersonDao

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }



    public int count(){

        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Import({RepositoryConfig.class})
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
    //<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"></context:property-placeholder>
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

RepositoryConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.hibernate.dao")
public class RepositoryConfig
{

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")     private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")                 private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")             private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")             private String password;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")         private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")     private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}") private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

    @Bean()    
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();        
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);        
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }


    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
          LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());

            sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);

            return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);

        return properties;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

    <display-name>Test App</display-name>

    <!-- There are three means to configure Wickets configuration mode and they 
        are tested in the order given. 1) A system property: -Dwicket.configuration 
        2) servlet specific <init-param> 3) context specific <context-param> The 
        value might be either "development" (reloading when templates change) or 
        "deployment". If no configuration is found, "development" is the default. -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.spring.config.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.TestApp</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>com.wicket.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.TestApp</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Pom.xml

...........

```
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.20.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.13.v20130916</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- allowed values: R7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 or none -->
    <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-kendo-ui</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-kendo-ui-theme-blueopal</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Database connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                        <port>8443</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
                        <password>wicket</password>
                        <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <wtpversion>${wtp.version}</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Apache Nexus</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

application.properties

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testSchema
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

I keep getting a null pointer in PersonDao at line 20 which is the sessionFactory being null, meaning i am not getting sessionFactory autowired, this is my first time trying to get non XML config working and I think I am missing something, help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are moving all configurations in java code than Instead of using XML in web.xml to register the Spring Dispatcher Servlet, we can move the bootstrap code into a Java class that implements the ServletContainerInitializerinterface. Please refer [this](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-2-java-based-configuration)

Comment: Also please upload your pom.xml

Comment: I cannot see the `application.properties` which you specified in `AppConfig` class, can you post that also.

Comment: It cannot be `null` if it would be a spring managed bean, spring would throw an exception at startup saying that the dependency couldn't be resolved. Make sure you aren't making new instances yourself instead of Spring.